# When the page loads, the item is completely painted over. It should be partially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the page loads, the item is completely painted over. It should be partially. If I click any arrow on an input element, it is partially painted over (what I need). What can I do to make it partially painted when the page loads?

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .border {
        fill: none;
        stroke: green;
        stroke-width: 1;
      }
      .sector {
        fill: none;
        stroke: green;
        stroke-width: 50;
      }
    </style>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="file.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg
      width="100px"
      height="100px"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
    >
      <circle class="sector" r="25" cx="50" cy="50" />
      <circle class="border" r="50" cx="50" cy="50" />
    </svg>
    <label>
      <span
        >YES %: <input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="78" id="yes"
      /></span>
    </label>
  </body>
</html>
```

file.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let yesValue = 78;
  document.getElementById("yes").innerHTML = yesValue;
  function setSector(part) {
    var radius = +$(".sector").attr("r"),
      width = 2 * Math.PI * radius,
      result = (width / 100) * part;
    $(".sector").css("stroke-dasharray", result + "," + width);
  }
  $("[type=number]").on("input", function() {
    var part = +$(this).val();
    setSector(part);
  });
});
```

Totally, I need partially painted circle and string :

```
YES % : 78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the function at the time of document.ready()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let yesValue = 78;
  setSector(yesValue);
  document.getElementById("yes").innerHTML = yesValue;
  function setSector(part) {
    var radius = +$(".sector").attr("r"),
      width = 2 * Math.PI * radius,
      result = (width / 100) * part;
    $(".sector").css("stroke-dasharray", result + "," + width);
  }
  $("[type=number]").on("input", function() {
    var part = +$(this).val();
    setSector(part);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .border {
        fill: none;
        stroke: green;
        stroke-width: 1;
      }
      .sector {
        fill: none;
        stroke: green;
        stroke-width: 50;
      }
    </style>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="file.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg
      width="100px"
      height="100px"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
    >
      <circle class="sector" r="25" cx="50" cy="50" />
      <circle class="border" r="50" cx="50" cy="50" />
    </svg>
    <label>
      <span
        >YES %: <input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="78" id="yes"
      /></span>
    </label>
  </body>
</html>
```